# Construir tabla HTML dinámica en PHP leyendo un array

Tags: php, html

Respondiendo a una pregunta intentaba crear una tabla dinámica a partir de un array obtenido de una consulta a la base de datos.

El array se presenta más o menos así:

```
  Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [caja] => Caja1
            [fecha_inicio] => 2017-07-31
            [totales] => 10|1000|14|2|0|976|203
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [caja] => Caja2
            [fecha_inicio] => 2017-08-01
            [totales] => 4|865|789|21|22|5|34|589
        )

)
```

La tabla tendría encabezados dinámicos: `caja` y `fecha_inicio` irían siempre, pero tengo que tener otros encabezados del tipo `D1, D2, D3...` dichos encabezados se tomarían de los valores en la clave `totales` del arreglo, donde cada valor entre `|` sería una columna de la tabla.

El problema es que dichos valores no son fijos, es decir, que en algunos casos podría tener 5 valores, en otros 7, en otros 6...

Yo he construido la tabla dinámica obteniendo el primer valor del array usando `reset`. Pero si ese primer valor tiene solamente cinco `|` en la clave `totales` la tabla se quedará pequeña para valores con más de cinco `|`.

La idea sería con un método parecido a `reset` obtener el valor que tenga mayor cantidad de separadores en la clave `totales` y en base a eso construir los encabezados de la tabla.

**¿Cómo podría hacer eso? ¿O habrá una forma más fácil de hacer lo que pretendo?**

---

Este es el código de construcción de la tabla dinámica:

```
   $strHtml="<table border='1'>";

/**
  * Obtenemos la primera fila del array con reset
  * para construir de forma dinámica los encabezados de la tabla
  * dado que la columna totales devuelve los datos así:
  * [totales] => 10|1000|14|2|0|976|203
  * haremos un explode y crearemos los encabezados de los días dinámicamente
  **/      

    $strCabeceras = reset($arrDatos);
    $strDias=explode("|",$strCabeceras["totales"]);

    $strHtml.="<th>CAJA</th>";
    $strHtml.="<th>FECHA INICIO</th>";

    $i = 1;
    foreach($strDias as $dia)
    {
        $strHtml.="<th>D$i</th>";
        $i++;
    }         
    $strHtml.="<tbody>";

    foreach ($arrDatos as $row)
    {
        $strHtml.= "<tr>";
        $strHtml.= "<td>".$row["caja"]."</td>";
        $strHtml.= "<td>".$row["fecha_inicio"]."</td>";
        $strDias=explode("|",$row["totales"]);

        foreach($strDias as $dia)
        {
            $strHtml.="<td>$dia</td>";
        }     

        $strHtml.= "</tr>";
    }

    $strHtml.="</tbody>";
    $strHtml.="</table>";
    echo $strHtml;
```

---

Este sería más o menos el resultado final de la tabla:

```html
<table border='1'><th>CAJA</th><th>FECHA INICIO</th><th>D1</th><th>D2</th><th>D3</th><th>D4</th><th>D5</th><th>D6</th><th>D7</th><tbody><tr><td>Caja1</td><td>2017-07-31</td><td>10</td><td>1000</td><td>14</td><td>2</td><td>0</td><td>976</td><td>203</td></tr><tr><td>Caja2</td><td>2017-08-01</td><td>4</td><td>865</td><td>789</td><td>21</td><td>22</td><td>5</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: Hay una cantidad máxima de items en total? De otro modo hay algún máximo items a colocar en la misma fila de la tabla?

Comment: @Juan no entendí tu pregunta. Si te refieres a las columnas `D1, D2...` no, podría haber 7, 5, 15... eso dependerá de los valores que haya en la BD.

Comment: Entonces la tabla de ancho no tiene límite y la cantidad de columnas Dn queda determinada por el registro que mas valores seaprados por | tenga. Cierto?

Comment: Respondiendo a la pregunta: No se puede, los totales son expresiones a evaluarse. Tu forma de representar los datos requiere de ante mano saber cuál es la expresión con más valores, así que tienes dos soluciones 1. Cambiar la forma de representación (lo más óptimo), 2. Solución de dos pasadas, una obtiene la expresión con más valores (cantidad) y la otra genera la tabla.

Comment: Correcto @Juan . Bueno, tampoco estamos hablando de una tabla con 500 columnas... pero la cantidad de columnas podría ser muy variable, dependiendo del valor de `D(n)`

Comment: @EduenSarceño los datos se obtienen así porque considero que es la forma más óptima para resolver el problema. No me gustaría tener que construir todo del lado de la base de datos.

Comment: @A.Cedano me refiero a que podrías cambiar la visualización del HTML, no la representación interna de la DB

Answer (score 4):

Me parece que no hay otra forma que recorrer el array 2 veces.
Una vez para determinar el registro que más valores tiene y otra para generar la tabla.

En la segunda vuelta, podés normalizar los valores del campo total convirtiéndolos en un array, y agregando elementos vacíos para completar el máximo de elementos determinados en la primera vuelta.

Ejemplo:
Supongamos que el máximo determinado es 10.

```
[totales] =>  4|865|789|21|22|5|34|589
```

(hay 8 elementos separados por |)

Para llegar a 10 faltan 2 (10 - 8 = 2).

Entonces convertimos:

```
[totales] => [4,865,789,21,22,5,34,589,'','']
```

Después podes volcar todos los campos a la tabla y van a quedar todos con el mismo ancho.

**EDICIÓN I**

Para determinar el máximo de elemenos se hace la primera recorrida del array:

Al array lo llamé $elementos.

```
$max = 0;

    for($i=0;$i<count($elementos);$i++){
        $totales = $elementos[$i][totales];
        $totales_arr = split('|',$totales);
        $nro_elementos = count($totales_arr);
        if($nro_elementos > $max){
            $max = $nro_elementos;
        }
    }
```

En $max te queda el número máximo para la segunda recorrida del mismo array.

**EDICIÓN II**

Para evitar el primer ciclo podés definir una funcion en la base de datos que tome un string como parámetro, parsee el string con el formato del campo valores, y cuente la cantidad de elementos.

Supongamos que la función se llama `func_cuenta`.

Luego el primer ciclo se podría reemplazar con un query:

```
select max(func_cuenta(valores)) from tabla_con_campo_valores;
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. El problema sería lo que llamas _máximo determinado_. No tengo forma de saber eso. En una consulta puede haber `totales` con un máximo de 8 valores, o de 5. O puede haber 15 valores como máximo. La idea es tener una tabla dinámica que se llene tomando como _máximo determinado_ la ocurrencia de totales que tenga mayor cantidad de valores. Estaba pensando en ir construyendo los elementos de la tabla por partes y luego ensamblar todo... pero creo que estaría ante el mismo dilema. O bien _obligar_ a la consulta SQL a que me llene `totales` uniformemente agregando `NULL`.

Comment: Con la edición de la respuesta entiendo mejor lo que planteas. Me parece que me decidiré por la 1ª posibilidad, ya que prefiero hacerlo de forma programática en PHP y no en la base de datos. En cuanto tenga un momento libre lo probaré y te comento el resultado. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Dependiendo de donde tomes los datos ya sea **MySQL** o **Array** *(como la estructura que colocaste en tu planteamiento)*; deberás usar **[mysqli_fetch_fields](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-fields.php)** o **[array_keys](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-keys.php)** según corresponda; con los dos anteriores obtendrías el nombre de los campos obtenidos o el nombre de cada referencia de array (recordar que ambos casos serían como array asociativo). Los que indicas fijos asignalos según sea por cálculo o como sea realizados las otra(s) columnas.

De esta forma llenarias el *`tbody`* del `table` a formar; ya desde luego con los mismo recorrer el elemento; ejemplo:

```
$strHtml="";
$strHTML.="<table>";
```

Si fuera el origen desde MySQL

```
// Origen Mysql >>
$info_campo = $resultado->fetch_fields();
$strHTML.="<thead>";
$strHTML.="<tr>";
foreach ($info_campo as $valor) {
  $strHTML.="<th>".$valor->name."</th>";
}
$strHTML.="</tr>";
$strHTML.="</thead>";
// << Origen Mysql
```

Si fuera el origen un array (similar al que planteaste); en el ejemplo a tu estructura la "asigne" a la variable `$array`.

```
// Origen Array>>
$info_campo = array_keys($array);
$strHTML.="<thead>";
$strHTML.="<tr>";
foreach ($info_campo as $valor) {
  $strHTML.="<th>".$valor."</th>";
}
$strHTML.="</tr>";
$strHTML.="</thead>";
// << Origen Array
```

Ahora que ya se tiene la forma de accederlo ya sea de MySQL (`$valor->name`) o Array (`$valor`) llenas el `tbody`.

```
$strHTML.="<tbody>";

[el foreach según sea de Mysql o Array el origen; $row es cada elemento]
   $strHTML.="<tr>";
   foreach ($info_campo as $valor) {
     $strHTML.="<td>".$row[$valor->name]."</td>"; // Si es MySQL
     $strHTML.="<td>".$row[$valor]."</td>"; // Si es Array
   }
   $strHTML.="</tr>";
[fin del foreach origen MySQL o Array]

$strHTML.="</tbody>";

$strHTML.="</table>";
```

y finalmente

```
echo $strHtml;
```

### EDITADO

Para lo que mencionas (y no me percate al principio); tendras que relizar un recorrido de todo el `Array` y para cada `total` aplicar [explode](http://php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php) obtienes con [count](http://php.net/manual/es/function.count.php) cuanto elementos tienes y si es el primero "asumes" es el mayor en caso contrario comparas si el valor es mayor del count actual es mayor al previo lo reemplazas, así por cada elemento claro esta, será necesario recorrer todo el array para obtener el mayor de D1, D2...D*n* y luego el proceso para generar el `table` commo lo requieres.

Comment: Gracias. El problema principal sería construir de forma dinámica las columnas `D1, D2, D3...` las cuales vienen en los resultados en una sola columna llamada `totales`. Se trataría de obtener dentro del array la clave `totales` que tenga más elementos y construir en base a ella dichas columnas, determinando que por cada valor entre `|` y `|` habrá una columna.

Answer (score 1):

La forma de representación requiere de ante mano saber cuántas columnas `D1, D2, D3, ..., Dn` a crear, donde `n = Max (count (totales_1), ..., count(totales_n))`.

Pseudocódigo

```
`numero_columnas` = Max (count (totales_1), ..., count(totales_n))
crear tabla
crear `numero_columnas` columnas 
for (cada `fila` en resultado_consulta)
{
    representar `fila` en HTML
}
```

Una implementacion de Max

```
function max_totales($cons)
{
    $ac = PHP_INT_MIN;
    foreach ($cons as $fila)
      {
        $tot_i = count(explode("|", $fila["totales"]));
        if($ac < $tot_i)
            $ac = $tot_i;
      } 
    return $ac;
}
```

El renderizado

```
function renderizar_tabla($cons)
{
    $html = "<table>\n";
    $html .= "\t<thead>\n";
    $html .= "\t\t<tr>\n";
    $html .= "\t\t\t<th>CAJA</th>\n";
    $html .= "\t\t\t<th>FECHA INICIO</th>\n";

    for ($i = 1; $i <= max_totales($cons); $i++)
        $html .= "\t\t\t<th>D" . $i . "</th>\n";

    $html .= "\t\t</tr>\n";
    $html .= "\t</thead>\n";
    $html .= "\t<tbody>\n";

    foreach($cons as $fila)
      {
        $html .= "\t\t<tr>\n";
        $html .= "\t\t\t<td>" . $fila["caja"] . "</td>\n";
        $html .= "\t\t\t<td>" . $fila["fecha_inicio"] . "</td>\n";

        foreach(explode("|", $fila["totales"]) as $d)
          {
            $html .= "\t\t\t<td>" . $d . "</td>\n";
          }

        $html .= "\t\t</tr>\n";
      }


    $html .= "\t</tbody>\n";
    $html .= "</table>\n";
    return $html;
}
```

Un ejemplo trivial
*Prueba.php*

```
<?php
$r =  Array
(
    "0" => Array
        (
            "caja" => "Caja1"
            ,"fecha_inicio" => "2017-07-31"
            ,"totales" => "10|1000|14|2|0|976|203"
        )

    ,"1" => Array
        (
            "caja" => "Caja2"
            ,"fecha_inicio" => "2017-08-01"
            ,"totales"=> "4|865|789|21|22|5|34|589"
        )

);

echo renderizar_tabla($r);
```

probándolo en consola

```
[eduen@EDUENPC Escritorio]$ php Prueba.php > prueba.html; cat prueba.html; firefox prueba.html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>CAJA</th>
            <th>FECHA INICIO</th>
            <th>D1</th>
            <th>D2</th>
            <th>D3</th>
            <th>D4</th>
            <th>D5</th>
            <th>D6</th>
            <th>D7</th>
            <th>D8</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Caja1</td>
            <td>2017-07-31</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>1000</td>
            <td>14</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>976</td>
            <td>203</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Caja2</td>
            <td>2017-08-01</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>865</td>
            <td>789</td>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>34</td>
            <td>589</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[image: resultado en un navegador]

cómo puedes ver el anterior código tiene una complejidad  *Omega(n)* y requiere de dos recorridos, una para identificar la cantidad de columnas a crear, y la otra para representar la información en *HTML*

Mi consejo es que cambies la representación del HTML, podrías simplemente listar los items en forma vertical, con ello tu algoritmo requeriría únicamente una pasada para generar la tabla.

*P.D:* No hace falta rellenar columnas faltantes.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. El problema es que el código no debe depender de que conozca de antemano la cantidad de datos que habrá dentro de totales, es algo que podría ser muy variable en un rango digamos entre 4 y 25. Si pongo 25 como máximo, la tabla quedaría algo ridícula cuando haya sólo 4 valores como máximo ¿no?

Comment: Es por eso que se recurre a la función `max_totales`, el cuál es el encargado de construir lo necesario. Si max_totales es 4 entonces sólo habrán 4 columnas. Prueba el código, da valores entrada y salida y verás que crece dinámicamente.